# Iterate through a string and append values to a list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, e-commerce

Hi I'm trying to extract the sizes from a pandas data frame and append to a list.

```
Variations
Size| Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5xXlarge; 
Size| Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5xlarge; 
Sizes| Small - ( only one mic tab); Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5Xlarge; 
Sizes| Small - ( only one mic tab); Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5Xlarge; 
SIZE - COLOR| L/XL - Lime; 2XL/3XL - Lime;
```

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
def size_extractor(data):

    size_list = []

    for char in data:
        if char == "|":

            if char == " ":
                continue

                size_list.append(char)

            elif char == ";":
                continue

    print(size_list)

    df['Variations'].apply(size_extractor)
```

Im trying to use `"|"` to initiate the extraction and grab characters in between `" "` and `";"`.

To end up with a list like this `[Medium, Large, Xlarge, 2Xlarge, 3Xlarge, 4Xlarge, 5xXlarge]`

Should I redo in a while loop?

Comment: Can you share the expected output that you want?

Comment: I need a list like this:[Medium, Large, Xlarge, 2Xlarge, 3Xlarge, 4Xlarge, 5xXlarge]

Comment: @RobertRivas What about the last line `SIZE - COLOR| L/XL - Lime; 2XL/3XL - Lime;`? What the result should be?

Comment: [L/XL - Lime, 2XL/3XL - Lime]

Comment: What I mean is, based on above data, what complete result you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much I figured out what I needed by using regular expressions from  another question I had.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Variations': ['Size| Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5xXlarge; ',
                    'Size| Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5xlarge; ',
                    'Sizes| Small - ( only one mic tab); Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5Xlarge;',
                    'Sizes| Small - ( only one mic tab); Medium; Large; Xlarge; 2Xlarge; 3Xlarge; 4Xlarge; 5Xlarge; ',
                    'SIZE - COLOR| L/XL - Lime; 2XL/3XL - Lime;']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


def size_extractor(data):
    size_list = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), data.split('|')[1].split(';')))
    print(size_list)


df['Variations'].apply(size_extractor)
```

[image: Output]

**Code Explanation**

`data.split('|')[1]`: splits the data at '|' and we are using later part

`split(';')`: splits the data at ';'

`lambda x: x.strip()` with `map()`: removes spaces before and after strings

`list()`: is used to access the generator output of `map()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def size_extracter(data):
    print(data)
    size_list = []
    size = ""

    for char in data:
        if char == "|":
            size_list.append(size)
            continue
        elif char == " ":
            size = ""
            continue
        else:
            size = size + char

    print(size_list)





df['Variations'] = df['Variations'].str.replace(r'^[^|]*\|\s*', '').str.replace(';', '|', regex=False)

df['Variations'].apply(size_extracter)
```